# Android FileProvider - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/ while trying to take a video

Tags: android, kotlin, illegalargumentexception

Currently, I am trying to take a video in my app with the following kotlin code snippet

```
    private fun dispatchTakeVideoIntent() {
        Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE).also { takeVideoIntent ->
            val pather = File(filesDir, "Videos")
            pather.mkdirs()
            val file = File(pather,"VideoFileName.mp4")
            takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "$packageName.fileprovider", file))

            takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager)?.also {
                startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE)
            }
        }
    }
```

But I am getting the following error at the 'takeVideoIntent.putExtra...' line.

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/...
```

I have the following provider in my manifest

```
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.app.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
```

And the xml provider paths file looks like this

```
<paths>
    <files-path path="my_docs" name="Videos/" />
</paths>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `filesDir` is your app's internal storage, and corresponds to a `<files-path>` element, not `<external-files-path>`.

Comment: @MikeM. Hmm, I see what you mean. Unfortunately I changed that and it still gives me the same error. Fixed the post to reflect that.

Comment: The `path` and `name` attribute values are backwards, too.

Comment: That was it, thank you!